# Licensed Windows Server 2016 randomly shuts down itself for no reason

Tags: windows

My Windows Server 2016 Essentials recently got a habit of randomly shutting itself down. I've searched the issue online and almost all suggestions were like server must be unlicensed so it shutdowns automatically. Mine *is* licensed (and it hasn't been doing this for like 2 years). Also unlike unlicensed shutdowns, this one shutdown once every week, usually after weekend, Monday or Tuesday mornings.

Has anyone seen an issue like this before?

Comment: Sounds like a scheduled task or a hardware problem.  We will need more information

Comment: To piggyback on @Ramhound's comment, review Task Scheduler's [`taskschd.msc`] history and the main page's column showing all tasks and sort by _Next Run Time_. There will also be logs in Event Viewer with information about the shutdown, but am unsure what logs to check.